# Including a plain HTML partial in middleman

Tags: ruby, sinatra, slim-lang, middleman

I am using middleman with the [middleman-slim](https://github.com/yterajima/middleman-slim) package to generate a static website. If I have a partial in a file named `_test.erb` or `_test.slim`, I can simply include it with the line

```
== partial 'layouts/test'
```

However, if this is just a plain .html file, it doesn't work. I've searched around with relatively little success. The options I can think of so far are:

1. Rename the files to .erb, which will work but I'd rather not.
2. Include the contents of the file using IO.read (e.g. `==IO.read('source/layouts/_test.html')`), which is also ugly

Is there a way I can register a handler for plain .html files to make this work in a simple way?

Answer (score 2):

This is currently an open issue with Middleman: https://github.com/middleman/middleman/issues/1206

Check the link for up do date info and a couple of workarounds.

My personal approach would be to create a simple helper for `IO.read` or `sprockets.find_asset`.

**UPD**: Thomas Reynolds has fixed this for you! Wait for Middleman 3.3.4 to be released or use it from Github via Bundler:

```
gem 'middleman', :git => 'git@github.com:middleman/middleman.git', :branch => 'v3-stable'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'd given up hope, to be honest, and written my own extension agains the current default branch. However, I can't get Thomas's version to work - could it be only for .svg files?

Comment: NVM; had a look at the code. Still, I'm not sure why, but I get "no template engine registered" when I provide an extension for the file, and without the extension it doesn't locate it at all.